# Поиск по параметрам

Tags: php, машинное-обучение

Сделал поиск:

- Название:
- Город:
- Адрес:

И тут критерий предприятия, какое нужно найти. Идет как checkbox.

```
function ext($text)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($text));
}

if($_POST['title']!='')   $title=ext($_POST['title']); else $title='';
if($_POST['street']!='')  $street=ext($_POST['street']); else $street='';
if($_POST['city']!='')    $city=ext($_POST['city']); else $city='';
if(isset($_POST['wifi'])) $prefix1='1'; else $prefix1='';
if(isset($_POST['bil']))  $prefix2='1'; else $prefix2='';
if(isset($_POST['sush'])) $prefix3='1'; else $prefix3='';
if(isset($_POST['kal']))  $prefix4='1'; else $prefix4='';
if(isset($_POST['kar']))  $prefix5='1'; else $prefix5='';
if(isset($_POST['nal']))  $prefix6='1'; else $prefix6='';

$db = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM tb_users
    WHERE street_cafe LIKE '$street' or name_cafe LIKE '$title' or city_cafe LIKE '$city' or prefix1 LIKE '$prefix1'
    or prefix2 LIKE '$prefix2' or prefix3 LIKE '$prefix3' or prefix4 LIKE '$prefix4' or prefix5 LIKE '$prefix5' or prefix6 LIKE '$prefix6'");
```

Как мне его укоротить? И сделать поиск нормальным. Результат работ работает только по улице названию городу, а с критериями проблема. Помогите решить вопрос. Ищет только по одному параметру.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надеюсь, это учебная задача, в будущем продумывайте архитектуру получше, чтобы не приходилось городить огороды.

```
//массивы соответвий для обычных полей и чекбоксов 
$fields=array('title'=>'name_cafe','street'=>'street_cafe','city'=>'city_cafe');
$checkboxes=array('wifi'=>'prefix1','bil'=>'prefix2','sush'=>'prefix3',
'kal'=>'prefix4','kar'=>'prefix5','nal'=>'prefix6');
//составляем запрос:
$req=array();
$vals=array();
foreach($fields as $k=>$field){
    if(array_key_exists($k,$_POST)){
        $req[]='`'.$field.'` like ?';
        $vals[]='%'.$_POST[$k].'%';
    }
}
foreach($checkboxes as $k=>$checkbox){
    if(array_key_exists($k,$_POST)){
        $req[]='`'.$checkbox.'`=1';
    }
}
if($req){
//подключаемся к базе
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE ".implode(' or ',$req));
$db->execute($vals);
$result = $db->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Почему то не хочет работать выводится запрос:
SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE `name_cafe` like ? or `street_cafe` like ? or `city_cafe` like ?1
Хотя ввел параметр name_cafe

Comment: всё правильно, это pdo и плейсхолдеры.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Запрос не работает. Или я не понял. Я просто не использовал классы в работе с базой данных. Как мне по-русский вывести?

Comment: я всё понял, он и не будет работать через mysql_* функции, для этого я в ответе и показал пример подключения через PDO. чтобы всё работало необходимо указать верные $host(хост), $dbname(имя базы данных), $user(логин),$pass(пароль)

Comment: Уж так уж пошло  кинь ссылку на класс. И еще а с msqli такая хрень не пройдет?

Comment: [PDO](http://ru2.php.net/pdo). mysqli пройдет, с некоторыми изменениями

Comment: Ок щас тогда на msqli попробую заюзать.